# Where are Activities stored

Tags: android, android-activity

Where are Android Activities stored in the computer memory? Is it on the heap or the call stack?
When using apps and starting several acitivites these Activities really seem to be organized in a LIFO-order.

Comment: An activity is just an instance of a class.  It's stored on the heap. The stack you speak of has nothing to do with storage.  Android itself (or rather, the DVM) keeps a stack of activities for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

> Where are Android Activities stored in the computer memory? Is it on the heap or the call stack?

All objects are stored on the heap. Activities are objects. Therefore, activities are stored on the heap.

> When using apps and starting several acitivites these Activities really seem to be organized in a LIFO-order.

So are Web pages in a Web browser. This does not imply that clicking on a link in a Web page causes you to descend deeper into a call stack.

Answer (score 0):

Activitiies stack is managed by your app depending on your configuration provided programatically or in AndroidManifest file. Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Here is activities stack playground and nice visualisation of how some parameters work: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.novoda.demos.activitylaunchmode